# How to resolve compileJava errors during heroku deployment?

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, intellij-idea

I worked as follows to deploy Intellij Spring Boot using gradle on heroku. I proceeded from the directory containing the source files.

```
> git init
> git add .
> git commit -m "first commit"
> heroku create
> git push heroku master
```

However, the following error occurred during the push process.

[image]

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> invalid source release: 11

After the problem occurred, a file called system.properties was also created in the source file and the following input was also entered.

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

But it is still unresolved. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to ensure your local development and your deployed instance are using the same version.

You specified a version with `system.properties` with content `java.runtime.version=11` but haven't provided an image of the updated log. The log still says you are installing JDK 1.8.

Furthermore you should specify a Java version that is currently being supported. You can find the versions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions

```
Java 7 - 1.7.0_302  
Java 8 - 1.8.0_292  
Java 11 - 11.0.11  
Java 13 - 13.0.7  
Java 15 - 15.0.3  
Java 16 - 16.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just face this problem following a course. Solve it by change the sourceCompatibility='17'(on my file) to '1.8' on my built.gradle file  [change sourceCompatibility='1.8' on build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNTkb.png)
and change the Gradle JMV on setting and JKD on project structure to 1.8.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Lgq.png)

duno if the last change anything, but worked for me.